# Store firebase document in a variable make me looses the references inside it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a user document from Firebase, in order to put it as a global variable in re-use it in some functions. One of them is `displaySavedPlaces()` which allows to get a list of all the "places" documents the user has bookmarked. This is stored as an array of references in Firebase. Here is how it looks:
[image]

I store everything during `onAuthStateChanged()` : I get the document related to the user uid, and I store it in a variable called `currentUser`, also with user uid and a reference to the document if I need to call it again:

```
let authChangeListeners = [];

export function onAuthChange(listener) {
    authChangeListeners.push(listener);
}

window.currentUser = null;

onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (userFirebase) => {
    // Si user firebase, on remplit user de la db
    if (userFirebase) {
        const userRef = doc(db, "users", userFirebase.uid);
        const userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);
        const userData = userDoc.data();
        currentUser = { uid: userDoc.id, ...userData, ref: userRef };
        const avatarRef = ref(avatarsImageRef, currentUser.customAvatar ?? "default-av.webp");
        currentUser.avatarUrl = await getDownloadURL(avatarRef);
    }

    authChangeListeners.forEach((listener) => {
        return listener(currentUser);
    });
});
```

Then when I'm doing my function `displaySavedPlaces` later, I have an error from Firebase:

> Type does not match the expected instance. Did you pass a reference from a different Firestore SDK?

It comes from the `getDoc()` function. The interesting thing is that this error is not happening every time, but randomly (2/3 times).

```
import { onAuthChange } from "./assets/javascripts/main";

onAuthChange(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
        displaySavedPlaces(user);
    } else {
    }
});

async function displaySavedPlaces(user) {
    elements.savedPlacesContainer.innerHTML = "";
    user.savedPlaces.forEach(async (elem) => {
        console.log(elem);
        const placeSnapshot = await getDoc(elem);
        const place = placeSnapshot.data();
        ...
    });
}
```

However, no matter if I have the error or not, the `console.log(elem)` always returns what seems to be the reference object.

I was able to debug it by passing the saved places in a different variable than inside `currentUser`. The references seems to be lost/affected during the currentUser variable filling. It's happening also when I'm simply doing `currentUser = userData` without creating any new object. Any idea why?

Comment: When the error occurs, what's the output from the `console.log(elem);` statement right before it?

Comment: Also note that we can't see how `savedPlaces` is populated, so it's hard to say what data in there triggers the error. I recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example

Comment: `savedPlaces` contains an array of references, it comes from `userData` and is passed to `currentUser`. I forgot to mention that the `console.log(elem)` returns the reference object everytime, even when I have the error. I checked and they have the same content 100% so I'm just wondering if the fact that I'm putting the array in a new variable `currentUser` unlinks something and makes it not-readable by firestore?

Comment: Maybe something I can add, I tried another approach, which is in my `onAuthStateChanged` to manually take every reference one by one from `userData.savedPlaces` through a `for`, push it in an array and replace `currentUser.savedPlaces` with this new array and in this case it works. So I guess the problem is about taking the array from the document and moving it into `currentUser`, something becomes "recreated" at this point but I don't understand what.

Comment: It's hard for us to help, because we can't see "when I'm doing my function `displaySavedPlaces` later". Most likely it's an issue with asynchronous code, but it's hard to say more without the minimal-but-complete repro.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard for me because StackOverflow is not intuitive at all. I just updated with the entire code to understand the context.

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/1aoi1ba/references_within_an_array_not_recognized_while/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you see any reason why it happens now that I gave the entire code? I don't see anything in the firebase documentation related to references inside array fields. I'm not able to understand why the references "seems" broken when the array is moved into another object